# REACT NATIVE : how to insert all pictures from JSON, by calling API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

**Here i tried to call API from my JSON pictures, but thing is that i am getting just one picture , instead of all 4 pics**

```
React.useEffect(() => {
      if (!data) { return; }
      data.forEach((dataItem,index) => {
        if (index > 5) { return; }
        let url = `https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${dataItem}/images`
                 //for example : https://dog.ceo/api/breed/australian/images
        fetch(url)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then(json => {
           setImages(prevState => ({...prevState, [dataItem]:json.message[0] }));
          })
      })
    },[])
```

Here i am inserting pics into FlatList:

```
<FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
 <Image
       style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
                source={{
               uri: images[item],
               }}

      />  
          <Text>Image: {images[item]}</Text>
```

I would be very glad if you help me

Comment: Why are you appending ` + json.message[2]` in the `useEffect` call? I'm pretty sure that'll create an unusable string of to URLs stuck together (assuming there's an item at index 2)

Comment: You are fetching and calling API inside `for` loop, so each time, server request is made. So first, make a code that calls the API only once and get the returned data in JSON/ARRAY only once as a whole. Then iterate through it with a loop. That will be more efficient.